# How can I get the Google+ profile picture of an email address?

Tags: javascript, php, google-plus

how can we get the profile pic of google+ only with the email? or in the worse case, get the user id with the email?

We have a list of clients with their emails, and we want to display their profile picture in that list.

Is this posible in Javascript or PHP?

Regards

Comment: I think this is possible with the [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/). PHP is the way to go as this is more server side.

Comment: Not sure about google you can look in to https://en.gravatar.com/

Comment: I have answered a similar question here. Please take a look to see how easy is to accomplish this with a totally free and open source project https://stackoverflow.com/a/46355569/845296

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving a user's public google/gmail picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606322/retrieving-a-users-public-google-gmail-picture)

Comment: Google+ has been shut down, now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Google does not allow you to get the profile picture just with the client's email. However, the API does allow.

Related: [Find Google+ avatar for given email address without OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243200/find-google-avatar-for-given-email-address-without-oauth)

Comment: Thanks, this helps us a lot!!! we can't search by email, but at least we can search by name.

Answer (score -1):

**There is an amazing API called gravatar**

Follow this steps below

first you need to create md5 hash for the email address.

then attach the md5 hash to below url

```
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{md5 hash of email address}
```

eg.

```
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50
```

read more about API at:

https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement