# Using a JavaScript variable to link an image in a image tag in HTML with DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to use a JavaScript variable which is equal to the url of an image in a html img tag. I need the following tag to be able to display the image that is tied to the variable.

```js
document.getElementById("id-of-img-tag").src = imgVar;

document.getElementById("id-of-img-tag").innerHTML = imgVar;
```

```html
<img id="id-of-img-tag" src=" " alt="img">
```

Both of the lines of JS result with the alternative being displayed for the img tag "img".

Comment: Are there any errors when you open the developer tools in your browser?

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is you are using `getElementById` to get the img element, but the element above has `id-of-img-tag` as the `class`, not the `id`.

Comment: No errors i have a console.log(imgVar); and it outputs the link to the image. and Yeah sorry typo but in the html file its id="id-of-img-tag"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Google+ avatar for given email address without OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243200/find-google-avatar-for-given-email-address-without-oauth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using `getElementBy`**Id**`()` method for `<image` **class** `="id-of-img-tag"...>`. Try `querySelector("`**.**`id-of-img-tag")` instead.
2. The second statement makes no sense. `innerHTML` will parse a string into HTML. `imgVar` is not a string nor is it even defined. `imgVar` should be just a simple string that literally represents the url of the image:

   ```
    var imgVar = "url of img"
   ```
3. Assign `imgVar` to the `src` attribute of `<img>`

### Demo

```js
var imgVar = "https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg";

document.querySelector(".id-of-img-tag").src = imgVar;
```

```html
<img class="id-of-img-tag" src="" alt="img">
```

Comment: Thanks this kind of worked however instead of the image is see [this](https://imgur.com/a/0IAQb) Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: What's the exact url of image?

Comment: So its for a google sign in page im wokring on for my website and I want the users profile pic to be displayed so its a link to the user's propfile pic. (image size: 96x96 and its a jpg) [image](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-tJGLlnSh3Gw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AGi4gfxnWSDqsu5WxCNRA3TIruSc1qrXfA/s96-c/photo.jpg)

Comment: If you mean the users profile pic like the ones we have here on this site?

Comment: yeah? but when google sends back the image it gives it as a var

Comment: That looks pretty easy compared to dealing with oAuth, good luck, @Turtle

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in your HTML code. You have assigned the  tag with a **class** of "id-of-img-tag", and then in your javascript, you are using getElementBy**Id**(). 
Because there isn't an **id** called "id-of-img-tag" nothing is changed, and so the browser sees an 'empty' **src** and displays the **alt** image

Also in the code, you supplied you are not defining imgVar, which is returning the 'undefined' error which you show.

Here's a working example:

```
<img id="id-of-img-tag" src="" alt="img">

let url = "https://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg";

document.getElementById("id-of-img-tag").src = url;
```