# Getting user profile name and image in Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-signin

I'm working on a web app that modifies a user's Google Calendar events and can display their user profile name and image(avatar). After doing some research I found out that:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/ Google Calendar API which is very intuitive but has no mention of getting a user's profile info.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/ Google sign-in API which is very intuitive but has a sign-in mechanism that seems completely different from the Calendar API.

Which one should I go for? Thank you.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243200/find-google-avatar-for-given-email-address-without-oauth

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister this looks good, but in order to use that I'll need Calendar API to be able to give me user's email address, which it can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the calendar's quickstart https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js there is

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
```

it returns [`gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2getauthinstance)
which has `currentUser.get()`. So you could

```
var profile = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get()
```

to get the [profile](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetid).

then `profile.getBasicProfile()` to obtain name, avatar and other.

Hope it's helpful.